# Как подставить переменную в Select [psycopg2]

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

У меня произошел переход на Postgresql в библиотеку psycopg2.
До этого я сидел на sqlite3
задача следующая
у меня до postgresql был такой запрос:

```
result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = ?', (user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
return bool(len(result))
```

а теперь мне нужно сделать схожий запрос в psycopg2.

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос был решен таким образом

```
crs = connection.cursor()

class all_user_class:
    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        user_id_select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = %s"
        crs.execute(user_id_select, (user_id,))
        result = crs.fetchone()
        return bool(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * from user where user_id = %(some_id)d', {'some_id': 1234})
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

или так

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = %d", (1234,))
```